# How to delete the range of columns in closedXML?

Tags: c#, .net, excel, epplus, closedxml

Ive been trying to convert the EPPlus version of functionality into ClosedXML , i was stuck on the line where u send starting column number and total number of columns to delete in EPPlus method like this :

```
wsData.DeleteColumn(17, wsData.Dimension.End.Column - 18);
```

ive tried the following in closedXML

```
var rangeToDelete = wsData.Range(wsData.Column(17).FirstCell(), wsData.Column(34).LastCell());
rangeToDelete.Delete(XLShiftDeletedCells.ShiftCellsLeft);
```

but it doesnt work , how to solve this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deleting a Range should also work, but if you want to delete whole columns the simpler solution is

```
wsData.Columns(17, 34).Delete();
```